# CSS grid-column-start making full width based on screen size

Tags: html, css

I am developing a website and I am taking over the front-end part, but I am not much of a front-end developer. I am creating my grid system.

This is my CSS.

```css
.form-row {
        margin-top: 25px;
    }
    
    .margin-top-10px {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
        grid-gap: 10px;
    }
    
    .grid-container > div {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    }
    
    .item-1-2 {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 2;
    }
    
    .item-2-4 {
        grid-column-start: 2;
        grid-column-end: 4;
    }
    
    .item-2-6 {
        grid-column-start: 2;
        grid-column-end: 6;
    }
    
    .item-1-3 {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 3;
    }
    
    .item-3-5 {
        grid-column-start: 3;
        grid-column-end: 5;
    }
    
    .form-label {
        min-width: 180px;
    }
    
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        .grid-container > div {
            
        }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="form-row">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div class="item-1-2">
                    <div class="form-label">
                        <label>EMAIL ADDRESS <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item-2-6">
                    <div>
                        <input />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

On the screen with width above 500px, it renders the `label` and the `input` control side by side as expected since I applied the following classes, `item-1-2` and `item-2-6`. But what I want to do is that, when the screen is 500px or lower, I want to remove those `grid-column-start` and `grid-column-end`. I just want the `div` to be normal block element. How can I do that?

I tried this.

```
.item-1-3 {
    grid-column-start: unset;
    grid-column-end: unset;
}
```

It does not work.

Comment: try `initial` instead

Comment: or simply remove `display: grid;` by making the element `display:block`

Comment: Thanks. That works.